# UILabel drawTextInRect pros and cons?

Tags: objective-c, performance, uiview, uilabel

I was watching Apple's WWDC videos and they said if you want to flatten the `UIView` hierarchy you can avoid adding your `UILabels` as subviews, instead call their `drawTextInRect` in your container View `drawRect`.

I would like to know the Pro and Cons for this!

Answer (score 0):

I should like to know what video you are watching and where it say this... The UILabel documentation specifically says *not* to do this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/iPad/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html

> You should not call this method directly.

Comment: I think he refers to "Session 318 - iOS Performance in Depth" of WWDC 2011 at about 37:10 into the video.